# How to correctly position an overlay on a card?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I have a series of game cards on a page that I want to be unlockable. I want a basic overlay to be over the cards while they are locked, however as of now the overlay either sits behind the card or takes up the whole window. I just want it to sit nicely over the card.

```css
.game-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px rgba(#000, .1);
  margin-bottom: 1.6%;
  background: $color_white;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 2s;
  
  .locked-overlay {
  // display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="games-container">
  <div class="games-wrapper">
    <div class="level-header">
      <h2>Games</h2>
    </div>
      <% @games.each do |game| %>
        <div class="game-card">
          <%= link_to game_path(game) do %>
            <div class="game-card-media">
              <div class="game-card-icon">
                <div class="level-icon type-<%= game.language.name %>">
                  <% problem = game.problems.order("RANDOM()").first %>
                    <% if game.icon_based %>
                      <%= image_tag "problem_icons/#{game.name.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')}/#{problem.question}" %>
                    <% else %>
                      <div class="text-icon">
                        <%= problem.question %>
                      </div>
                    <% end %> <!-- icon selection -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <h1 class='game-card-action btn-primary'>Play!</h1>
            </div>
          <% end %> <!-- link to game path -->
          <div class="description">
            <%= link_to game_path(game) do %>
              <h1><%= game.name %></h1>
            <% end %>
            <h2><%= game.language.name %></h2>
            <p>Test your <%= game.language.name.capitalize %> vocabulary!</p>
            <p>- Difficulty: <%= game.difficulty.capitalize %></p>
            <p>- Category: <%= game.category.capitalize %></p>
            <p>- Author: <%= display_authors(game).html_safe %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="locked-overlay"></div>
      <% end %> <!-- games iteration -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try moving .locked-overlay div inside .game-card div and use position relative on .game-card css

Comment: Ohhh dang, that actually solved the issue. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

To have the overlay absloutely positioned to cover the card only the card only needs to be positioned, as the absolute positioned element follows the first positioned parent, here's a simple example.

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
}

.card-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-data">card data</div>
  <div class="card-overlay">card overlay</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I follow this example the entire window goes black, the overlay doesn't seem to be contained within the card.